# Form Hides Behind Screen Form Location X and Y Negative After ShowDialog()

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, .net-2.0, showdialog

I am working with a dual monitor screen.I have a situation where form is going behind the main form.I kept a log file that tracks the form move and location changes.I keep writing the log file with form Position.

I observed that form location is negative after form is shown.
So i calculated center of screen and before form show wrote following code.

```
iLeft = (VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width) / 2) - (VB6.PixelsToTwipsX(frmForm.Width) / 2)
iTop = (VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height) / 2) - (VB6.PixelsToTwipsY(frmForm.Height) / 2)

frmDataForm.SetBounds(iLeft, iTop, 0, 0, Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified.X Or Windows.Forms.BoundsSpecified.Y)
```

I tried the following fix and it worked for some scenarios.

```
  Private Sub frmDataForm_Move()
  If Me.Location.X < 0 And zbFirstLoad Then
        CenterForm(0, Me)
        zbFirstLoad = False
  ElseIf Me.Location.X > 0 AndAlso Me.Visible Then
        zbFirstLoad = False
  End If
```

On form load i set bool variable true everytime.

```
 zbFirstLoad = True
```

However when message box opens then messsage box goes behind the main screen.
I have 3 questions with respect to above scenario

1. Why is form always going at negative location even when form Startposition property is set to Centerscreen or Parentscreen.
2. How can we make Message box displayed in center
3. Is there other way to solve this.This solution does not work for all forms.

NOTE:This issue occurs at dual monitor.Also this issue occurs only on one dual monitor at not anywhere else.

Kindly reply..!

Comment: There is some missing information in this code. Please, update it such that your exact conditions can be reproduced easily; for example: code in the Form Load Event, with values for all the relevant variables (defined as a function of the given screen dimensions).

Comment: @varocarbas I have made edits..

Comment: Thanks, but perhaps I didn't make myself clear enough. I meant something on the lines of: "I write: " `Me.Left = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width/2 Me.Top = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height/2` "...but my form is not located in the center of the screen". That is: a set of inputs which might easily be reproduced on a different computer.

Comment: @varocarbas I have made edits for left and top.My question is how to center MessageBoxes and What could be the root cause..Third question is is there any better way to solve the issue.

Comment: Obvious reasons are having a form that's larger than the screen and having the 2nd monitor to the left of the 1st so it always has negative coordinates.  Obvious reasons for the Location or Bounds properties not working is forgetting to set the StartupPosition property to Manual.  None of which has anything to do with Z-order.

Comment: @HansPassant form is smaller than screen size in my case and also the 2nd monitor is placed on the right of first monitor.The problem is form is getting displayed at the left edge of 1st main screen window.I mean only border is visible.I press alt+spacebar select move and then drag it to desired location...Kindly reply...i am stuck... :(